# AngularJS linking model to ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create an `<input-field>` directive, which has basic form validation.

I need to the markup to be able to look like this

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input name="street_address_1" ng-model="customer.street_address_1" />
    <span class="fa fa-check fa-fw" ng-show="customerCreateForm.street_address_1.$valid"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-times fa-fw" ng-show="customerCreateForm.street_address_1.$invalid"></span>
</div>
```

I started writing the directive, but the `ng-show` attributes are not linked to the model correctly.

```
myApp.directive('inputField', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            fieldName: '@name',
            fieldModel: '=ngModel',
            fieldForm: '=form',
            required: '@'
        },

        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="form-group has-feedback">' +
                  '    <input name="{{ fieldName }}" ng-model="fieldModel" ng-required="required" />' +
                  '    <span class="fa fa-check fa-fw form-control-feedback" ng-show="fieldForm[fieldName][$valid]"></span>' +
                  '</div>'
    }    
});
```

And this is how I use the directive:

```
<input-field name="street_address_1" ng-model="customer.street_address_1" form="customerCreateForm" required />
```

**Edit:**

Here is a plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gVY2BpkqNSKBTHcjteNw?p=preview

Comment: Can you please post a plunkr of this.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're doing but have you looked at the transclude option for directives? It allows you to pass in arbitrary markup to your directive's template... Also, a plunkr for your current could would surely help

Comment: Also a solution using transclude would likely require using ngModelController so your directive could work with any ng-model values in the "arbitrary" markup that you pass in

Comment: There is now a plunkr, and I changed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
ng-show="{{fieldForm.$name}}.{{fieldName}}.$invalid"
```

it produces:

```
<span class="fa fa-check fa-fw form-control-feedback ng-hide" 
      ng-show="customerCreateForm.street_address_2.$valid">
</span>
```

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8l3Mv44hVGZ0Pzg3OGkP?p=preview)